# Tuple object has no attribute text

Tags: python, lxml

I am writing a code to get  specific information from yahoo finance website

```
    page = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=%s')
    tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
    annual_report = tree.xpath('//td[@class="yfnc_datamoddata1"]/text()')
    annual_report
```

Where `%s` is a name of a stock. If I manually input a name of a stock everything works great. But if I try to run a for loop for a list that I made,

```
    for x in my_list:
        page = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=%s'),(x,)
        tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
        annual_report = tree.xpath('//td[@class="yfnc_datamoddata1"]/text()')
        print annual_report
```

I get an error on tree line `'tuple' object has no attribute 'text'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is:

```
page = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=%s'),(x,)
```

Instead of formatting the string, you made 'page' a tuple.
This should work:

```
page = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=%s' % (x,))
```

Answer (score 1):

> `page = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=%s'),(x,)`

This is not how to define a format string. You accidentally created a tuple `('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=%s', x)`

To incorporate `x` into the string write it like this:

`page = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=%s' % x)`

Or even better because not needing specifiers:

- `page = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s={0}'.format(x))`
- `page = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=' + x)`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation